# jQuery Selection of elements created run time

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following scenario:

I have a `div = "#div1"` which is coded in html. I have populated this div with some data coming from a script service [ which means the "a's" are not there initially], and the data is appended to this div as

```
<a href=''>data1</a>
<a href=''>data2</a>
```

I have a jQuery selector like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1 a").click(function(){
      // do something
   });
});
```

This is not selecting the element. How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another simple and obvious solution in this case would be to push the click registration until the data is completely rendered!

Answer (score 5):

`#div1 a` matches anchors in this markup:

```
<div id="div1"><a href="#">test</a></div>
```

JS..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1 a").click(function(){
      alert('test');
   });
});
```

Please check for user errors/typos.

**If you are appending data after an ajax call, you need to use `.live`:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1 a").live('click', function(){
      alert('test');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The anchor elements don't exists yet when the `click` event handler is bound, but you can use the [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method, which uses [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1 a").live('click', function(){
      // do something
   });
});
```

`live` will match current *and future* elements on the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Live everyone else says:
Use the live method.